# How to get Json input in CakePhp Restful API using PUT

Tags: php, json, api, rest, cakephp

I am able to `view` and `delete` the data by passing ID in the URl in format of:

```
/apis/view/id.json
```

using:

```
public function view($id) {
        $api = $this->Api->findById($id);
        $this->set(array(
            'api' => $api,
            '_serialize' => array('api')
        ));
    }
```

Similarly I want to implement `add` and `edit`, where I can pass data in Json format in the HTTP body and store/edit it in the database.

I couldn't follow the this solution:
[CakePHP API PUT with JSON input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605975/cakephp-api-put-with-json-input)

I couldn't understand how to use

```
$data = $this->request->input('json_decode');
```

to achieve it.

Comment: Please always mention the exact CakePHP version you are using.

Comment: Thanks @ndm. I am using 2.0

Comment: I think you are going to hit other issues if you look into how CakeRequest works you can see that this is not going to work out of the box if you send the payload as Content-Type:application/json so you might need more work for that. You can check some plugins that we open sourced recently https://github.com/Wizehive/cakephp-api-utils

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add can simply be used as given in documentation by appending .json to it. The URL at which you post the data will become `/apis.json`. This will automatically access the add() method.

Assuming you pass json values email and password in such format: `{"email":"abc@def.com","password":"123456"}`

```
public function add(){

     $data=$this->request->input('json_decode', true ); //$data stores the json 
//input. Remember, if you do not add 'true', it will not store in array format.

     $data = $this->Api->findByEmailAndPassword($data['email'],$data['password']);
//simple check to see if posted values match values in model "Api". 
         if($data) {$this->set(array(
                          'data' => $data,
              '_serialize' => array('data')));}
        else{ $this->set(array(
            'data' => "sorry",
            '_serialize' => array('data')));}

      }//  The last if else is to check if $data is true, ie. if value matches,
      // it will send the input values back in JSON response. If the email pass
      // is not found, it will return "Sorry" in json format only.
```

Hope that answers your question! Put is also very similar, except it will check if the data exists, if it doesn't it will create or else it will modify existing data. If you have any further doubts don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Hi thanks @Anugrah! After commenting SavedByEmail.. line and adding:
$this->Api->create(); $this->Api->save($data); datas are now pushing to database. What to do to populate crated and modified field in database?

Comment: Just do the same thing, if formhelper finds an already populated field it will automatically assume editing is required. Here's the link:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

go through the thing you'll understand. :)

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [the linked documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-xml-or-json-data), `CakeRequest::input()` reads the raw input data, and optionally passes it through a decoding function.

So `$this->request->input('json_decode')` gives you the decoded JSON input, and in case it's formatting follows [the Cake conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html), you can simply pass it to one of `Model` save methods.

Here's a very basic (untested) example:

```
public function add()
{
    if($this->request->is('put'))
    {
        $data = $this->request->input('json_decode', true);

        $api = $this->Api->save($data);
        $validationErrors => $this->Api->validationErrors;

        $this->set(array
        (
            'api' => $api,
            'validationErrors' => $validationErrors,
            '_serialize' => array('api', 'validationErrors')
        ));
    }
}
```

This will try to save the data and return the save result as well as possible validation errors.

In case the formatting of the input data *doesn't* follow the Cake conventions, you'll have to transform it accordingly.